# What is the redirect_uri for a Facebook bookmark?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

On an ipad, when using Facebook in safari, there are bookmarks for apps which go to mobile web versions. The url looks like this:

apps.facebook.comm/namespace/?ref=bookmarks&code=abc..&fb_source=bookmark_apps&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0

In order to exchange the code for a token from the endpoint /oauth/access_token, I need the redirect_uri. What is it?

I have tried every possible combination of query string parameters and even left it out and the response is always the redirect_uri is incorrect.

Comment: i've the same problem , please submit it to this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/533389263372315

Comment: Did u ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same one.